# Application that temporarily overrides Group Policy for any user?

Tags: windows-7

I am looking for a application/program that would ideally have these features:

- Can be used to temporarily override group policy settings
- Light weight and easy to install
- Easy to use
- When logged in as a standard user, I can use this program, run it as administrator, and have vast options to enable/disable certain group policies that may be in effect. This would be useful for troubleshooting.
- Cheap
- Runs on Windows 7

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for you I may have a solution for this. [ControlUp](https://www.smart-x.com/downloads/) sounds like what your looking for. I have used it a few times.

The benefits I have noticed are as follows....

- Makes end user support far more easier
- ControlUp is very easy to use
- If you ever ran into a scenario such as e.g. CMD was blocked by group policy, you could easily run as administrator and temporarily override this setting even if this was in place by a domain group policy setting, allowing for making the job easier and simplier. E.g. for support purposes
- ControlUp has the ability to disable all group policy restrictions that are in place. Of course only temporarily

It also runs on Windows 7. There is also a trial version available (30 days) and gives you the same experience as the Pro and Enterprise version. There is also a free version if you don't want to pay - see the [pricing page](https://www.smart-x.com/products/controlup/pricing/) for more details.. It is limited to 50 concurrent sessions though and is quite restricted in features, but can still do what you want.

There is also a [helpful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOjQYQ00woM) of it in action.

Hope it helps. :)